# How to install MEAN stack on cent os

Tags: angularjs, node.js, linux, centos

I am new to stack I have been trying to learn MEAN Stack but unable to install it on Cent OS 7. I have a system with the following configurations
1. i7 Proccessor 
2. 12 GB RAM 
3. 512 GB Hard Disk

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add yum repository of node.js to the system by running the following commands in succession to add the yum repository.

```
# yum install -y gcc-c++ make
# curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Then install nodejs using

```
# yum install nodejs
```

This will also install npm for you, now you're good to go for using nodejs and express (**E** and **N** of M**E**A**N** stack)

You also need to setup mongodb if that is what you need to use as database ideally MEAN stack uses mongodb for that please follow their official documentation [Here is the link to it](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.8/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/). That takes care of **M** of **M**EAN stack.

Now for the **A** part you need Angular I would suggest you look at the versions of Angular available and based on it choose how to set it up they have pretty good documentation. You can choose from AngularJS, Angular 2 or Angular 4.

Hope this helps.